# skipping choma part reading in yuv 420 using fseek

Tags: c

I wants to read only Luma content from the 4-2-0 YUV input.
I wrote a code for that which works fine and able to dump only luma content into a separate file.

**CODE:**

```
int main() 
{
    size_t size = 0;
    uint32_t frame_number = 0;
    
FILE* f0_in = fopen("input_420p.yuv", "r");
if (NULL == f0_in) {
    printf("REF: Error in opening input file \n");
    return 0;
}

FILE* f0_luma = fopen("input_420p_LumaContent.y", "w");
if (NULL == f0_luma) {
    printf("REF: Error in opening output file for luma \n");
    return 0;
}

uint32_t width_luma = 1632;
uint32_t height_luma = 1280;

uint32_t width_chroma = width_luma/2;
uint32_t height_chroma = height_luma/2;

uint32_t luma_size = width_luma * height_luma;
uint32_t chroma_size = width_chroma * height_chroma;

uint32_t frame_size = luma_size + 2*chroma_size;

unsigned char *inputLumaY;
unsigned char *inputChromaCB;
unsigned char *inputChromaCR;

inputLumaY = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * width_luma * height_luma);
if (inputLumaY == NULL) {
    exit (1);
}

inputChromaCB = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * width_chroma * height_chroma);
if (inputChromaCB == NULL) {
    exit (1);
}

inputChromaCR = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * width_chroma * height_chroma);
if (inputChromaCR == NULL) {
    exit (1);
}

/* frame loop */
while (!feof(f0_in))
{

    size =  fread(inputLumaY, 1, luma_size, f0_in);
    if (size == 0) {
        printf ("REF: Error in reading luma content: %zu\n", size);
        break;
    }

    size += fread(inputChromaCB, 1, chroma_size, f0_in);
    if (size == 0) {
        printf ("REF: Error in reading cb content: %zu\n", size);
        break;
    }

    size += fread(inputChromaCR, 1, chroma_size, f0_in);
    if (size == 0) {
        printf ("REF: Error in reading cr content: %zu\n", size);
        break;
    }


    if (size == frame_size)
    {
        fwrite((void *)inputLumaY, sizeof(unsigned char)  , luma_size, f0_luma);

    }

    printf("Frame number:%d\n",frame_number);

    frame_number++;


}
  
free(inputChromaCR);
free(inputChromaCB);
free(inputLumaY);
fclose(f0_in);
fclose(f0_luma);

return 0;
}
```

**Query:**
I want to skip reading chroma part and wants to use `fseek` instead. So, because of fseek code will point to the next luma frame index for the next frame.

Can any one suggest the way for doing so.

**Reason:** I want to operate on Luma and wants to avoid the chroma buffer allocation in code. If I will able to replace file reading for chroma, then I will remove chroma buffer allocation.

Comment: Unrelated, but may save you some typing: You don't need to cast `void*` to any other type of pointer so, `... = (unsigned char*) malloc(...);` could just be `... = malloc(...);` and `sizeof(unsigned char)` (or `char` or `signed char`) is defined to be exactly `1`, so ... no need for that either. Just replace `sizeof(unsigned char) *` with `1` everywhere.

Comment: @TedLyngmo,Some time as per coding guidelines I need to put this .But thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: `fseek(f0_in, SEEK_CUR, chroma_size * 2)`

Comment: See [Why is `while(!feof(fp))` always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941)

Comment: @user3386109, `fseek(f0_in, SEEK_CUR, chroma_size * 2)` doesnot give proper result. Its dumping the chroma resollution image also in output file.

Comment: @user3386109,it should be `fseek(f0_in, chroma_size * 2, SEEK_CUR);` .

Comment: Yes, the last two parameters are switched.

Comment: Please provide this as answer, so I can accept this as answer.